# Cognos Report Studio 10.x- Using different rates in different lines

Tags: cognos

I have the following crosstab using a DMR :

```
                          201201
                      Real   Forecast
 Car's  Revenue       XXXX   AAA * IGPM
 Bike's Revenue       YYYY   BBB * ISS
```

and I have a taxes table :

```
 Period      Tax     %
 201201      IGPM   1,5
 201201      ISS    0,5
```

How I calculate the measure Forecast, that depending on the line (account) and period, the rate to be used is different.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In your Revenue table you must need an item Tax which indicates the Tax used for the Forecast item. Then you can right-click to the crosstab and go to query. Here, you apply a filter like the following :
Revenue.Tax=Taxes.Tax and Revenue.Period=Tax.Period

Finally you create a calculated measure (maybe you cannot make this in a cross tab, so choose a list) Taxes.% * Revenue.Real